# how to parse the following file

Tags: c++, string, parsing, line

I have a little issue transfer some python code to C++ 
i have a file with format like:

```
============================== There are    0   element
============================== There are    62  element
1VTZ0   13  196 196 13  196 196 184 2520    2BUKA   1   1VTZ0   1   195
1VTZ1   13  196 196 13  196 196 184 2520    2BUKA   1   1VTZ1   1   195
1VTZ2   13  196 196 13  196 196 184 2350    2BUKA   1   1VTZ2   1   195
1VTZ3   13  196 196 13  196 196 184 2470    2BUKA   1   1VTZ3   1   195
1VTZ4   13  196 196 13  196 196 184 2560    2BUKA   1   1VTZ4   1   195
1VTZ5   13  196 196 13  196 196 184 2340    2BUKA   1   1VTZ5   1   195
1VTZ6   13  196 196 13  196 196 184 3320    2BUKA   1   1VTZ6   1   195
1VTZ7   13  196 196 13  196 196 184 2820    2BUKA   1   1VTZ7   1   195
1VTZe   13  196 196 13  196 196 184 2140    2BUKA   1   1VTZe   1   195
```

what I want to do is skip the line `===================== There are 0 element`.
in my original python code i simply need to use the if condition:

```
 if (not "====="  in line2) and (len(line2)>30):
```

i used a similar if condition in C++ but still can not get rid of the "element" line, my c++ code is following:

```
 unsigned  pos1, pos2;
 string needle1="element"
 string needle2="====="
 Infile.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in);
 while (!Infile.eof())
 {

    if(line==" ")
    {
       cout<<"end of the file" <<endl;
       break;
    }

    getline(Infile, line);
    pos1=line.find(needle1);


    if (pos1!=string::npos&& pos2!=string::npos && (line.length()> 40))
    {
        ...........
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: `needle1` is `"====="`, right?

Comment: Where/how is `line` defined?

Comment: First, the `eof()` test is almost guaranteed to *not* be what you want for your loop-termination condition. Next, since none of your quantified data lines start with '=', I'd test for that, reading one line at a time using [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) discarding lines starting with '='. Finally, I'd send any valid data lines through a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) for individual element parsing. into data fields.

Comment: yes...I add the needle "======" into the file..above but the problem is still  "Cannot convert string 'element' to Int8"  i think i still not skip that line in some reasons....

Comment: mbratch:  i used: string line; getline(Infile, line);

Comment: whozcraig...i have tokenizer() functions to parse the line i want...but the issue is i cannot get rid of the line with certain needles .....

Comment: @user1830108 I'm more talking about std library usage and form. [See this sample](http://ideone.com/kvf0WA) which reads your object files into a vector of structures. It is obviously skeleton, but note the the use of `std::getline()` in the while-expression, and the skipping of lines starting with '='. The sample can easily be adapted to use a `std::ifstream` rather than `std::cin` for the input source, and obviously your specific needs and translations may vary, but the bottom line remains: don't reinvent the wheel unless you have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't particularly know why you're checking line lengths, as there are better ways to do this.

For example, you could index the string (as it's an array of characters), and then use a `continue` statement inside your while loop.

```
while (!Infile.eof()){    
  if (line[0] == '=') { // this assumes that no other lines start with '='
      continue;
    }

  if(line==" "){
     cout<<"end of the file" <<endl;
     break;
  }

  // Do whatever you need to do with the non "===... XX element" lines
```

}

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/58-break-and-continue/

Comment: alex: that's because the file i need to parsed is more complicated than what I show...so i have get rid of the lines with others needles ...but it looks like I was not able to get the rid of the "element" needle line using my code and I do not quite clear why is that

Comment: I have a further question about the (line[0] == '=') the complier will report  "comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour" " ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer"....?

Comment: @user1830108  `line` looks like a std:string, but is not `line[0]` a `char` and thus comparable to `=`?